# Как при сравнении указать буквы разных языков и регистров одинаковыми?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Программа с помощью `line.strip()` удаляет повторяющиеся строки в файле. Как на Python сделать модификацию, считающую буквы o c e p русского и английского алфавита и буквы разного регистра (п П р Р к К) одинаковыми (без привода слов к одному регистру)?

Пример:

это повтор строки.

этo пoвтoр стрoки.

ЭтО пОвТоР сТрОкИ.

эTo пOвToP cTpOкИ.

после анализа модификация должна оставить только первую строку

```
inp = input('Укажите путь к файлу(с названием и типом(.txt):\n')
text = open(inp, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
line = [line.strip() for line in text]
uniq = []
[uniq.append(x) for x in line if x not in uniq]
text.close()
exp = input('Укажите куда сохранить отредактированную копию(с названием и расширением файла):\n')
redact = open(exp, 'w')
for index in uniq:
    redact.write(index + '\n')
redact.close()
```

Comment: Приводите к одному регистру во временном списке и проверяйте или создайте словарь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*исходный 12.txt*

```
Пример:
это повтор строки.
этo пoвтoр стрoки.
ЭтО пОвТоР сТрОкИ.
эTo пOвToP cTpOкИ.
после анализа модификация должна оставить только первую строку
```

*Программа*

```
# f8ef45078d9742c98f8fa35d1e51117f.py
# Date: September 25th, 2020.

EQ = \
{
    'o':'о', 'c':'с',
    'e':'е', 'p':'р',
    't':'т'
}
def GetModifed(string: str):
    """ Возвращает модифицированную строку."""
    string = string.lower()
    for en, ru in EQ.items():
        string = string.replace(en, ru)
        
    print(string)
    return string

file = input("file: ")

data = None
previous = None
to_remove = list()
with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    data = fp.read()
for ln_index, ln in enumerate(data.split('\n')):
    current = GetModifed(ln.strip())
    if current == previous:
        to_remove.append(ln_index)
    previous = current

if input(f"Rewrite file {file}? [y/n] ") == 'y':
    with open(file, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fp:
        for ln_index, ln in enumerate(data.split('\n')):
            if not ln_index in to_remove:
                fp.write(ln + '\n')

print(to_remove)
```

К каждой строке применяются некие модификаторы и она сравнивается с предыдущей, а после уже она сама становится предыдущей. Таким образом можно узнать индексы строк, которые после применения модификаторов являются эквивалентными.

*Вывод*

```
F:\Users\Shamus_Rezol\Desktop\Programs>f8ef45078d9742c98f8fa35d1e51117f.py
file: 12.txt
пример: <- строки 12.txt после метода GetModifed
это повтор строки.
это повтор строки.
это повтор строки.
это повтор строки.
после анализа модификация должна оставить только первую строку
Rewrite file 12.txt? [y/n] y
[2, 3, 4]  <- индексы удаленных строк
```

*Итоговый 12.txt*

```
Пример:
это повтор строки.
после анализа модификация должна оставить только первую строку
```